# Add media from gallery to wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, image-gallery, cron-task

I'm working on a wordpress blog and I'm facing some problems that I need help with. I'm not an experienced coder or wordpress user, please keep it simple :)

I'm using jetpack as i love the mosaic tiles gallery, this is where my problem rise. I want to use a RSS feed to fetch photo content to my blog, these photos needs to be placed on the main page (static page).

Jetpack use this line to create the mosaic gallery:

```
[gallery type="rectangular" columns="5" link="file" ids="40,41,42,43,44,45,29,23,22,21,20,19,18,16,17,15,13,14,12,11,10,8,9,7" orderby="rand"]
```

I need a way when feedwordpress fetch pictures and add them to media library to add those new pictures to the existing page, in this case add 45, 46, 47 and so on.

Any ideas? Or plugins that are out of the box available?

Comment: Did a small change

[gallery type="rectangular" columns="5" link="file" ids="CHANGED THIS TO ALL" orderby="rand"]

Now it shows only 5 pictures at the page, when i refresh random pictures from the gallery are shown. How to show more then 5 items ? 

Almost there..

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best way to do i guess.

@echo off
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10000) do echo %%x,>> numbers.txt

added those as ids, now loads everything in media library